# Султан, ага, бей, эфенди — через дефис?

Tags: орфография, ономастика, раздельно-дефис

В именах собственных слова ***султан, ага, бей, эфенди*** пишутся через дефис или без него? Например, Бидар султан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В именах собственных слова **султан, ага, бей, эфенди** пишутся через
>   дефис или без него? Например, Бидар султан.

**"ага" и "бей" — всегда через дефис. см. ответ Людмилы.

В отношении таких членов составного имени, как "султан" и "эффенди", нельзя сказать однозначно.**

Дело в том, что они, строго говоря, не являются частью восточной "фамилии" и могут использовать как самостоятельные именующие единицы. 
"Эффенди" вообще используется примерно в той же функции как наше "господин" (или в CCCР — "товарищ"). По счастью, имена с "эффенди" очень редки и, когда оно стоит **перед** именем, то и пишется раздельно, дефисное написание тут не применимо.

А вот в отношении "султана" зачастую тут только чутье может подсказать, в какой функции оно использовано. И чутьё это часто обманывает.

Вот вам пример https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD,_%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD
**Амет-хан Султан.**

> В различных источниках есть разночтения по его имени:
>
> согласно советским документам военного времени (наградным листам),
>   фамилия — Амет-Хан, имя — Султан, отчества нет;
>
> согласно крымско-татарскому обычаю пишется слитно Аметхан Султан, без 
>   отчества и фамилии;
>
> он сам себя, его родственники и коллеги называют его по имени Амет;
>   Султан — имя его отца;
>
> в соответствии со свидетельством о рождении — Амет Султанович Амет-хан.

Ну это хорошо, хоть он все-таки гражданин СССР. Есть какие-то документы на русском, на которые можно ориентироваться. А что делать с турком с таким именем?!
Боюсь, что меньшим из зол здесь будет **раздельное написание и с заглавной**. Оно чаще всего соответствует выполняемой роли самостоятельной именующей единицы, а не дополнения к предшествующей структуре, о чем говорит Лопатин.

Comment: Простите, Бегемотус, не нравится мне: "А вот в отношении... то".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но меня интересует слово султан не как имя, а принадлежность к султану. Например, Бидар султан - это жена султана, Сениха султан - это сестра султана. Как быть со знаками в этих случаях?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой ок, спасибо

Comment: @Людмила ну из вашего вопроса это трудно было понять. Тут-то, пожалуй, стоит говорить о том, как писать  эти "сениха" и "биндер". Вот они-то по своей роли вполне соответвуют всяческим "ибн-", "-кызы", "-оглы" и прочим "аффиксам", упоминаемым у Лопатина. Но это опять же в именах. Если это титул, то уже нет нормирующих источников. Впрочем, я подумаю, потом, если что надумаю, дополню ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В справочнике Лопатина:

> § 124. Пишутся через дефис:
>
> 1. Двойные (редко тройные) фамилии
>
> ..................
>
> 3. Арабские, тюркские, персидские личные имена с составными частями, обозначающими социальное положение, родственные отношения и т. п., а
>    также служебными словами — такими, как ага, ад, ал, аль, ар, ас, аш,
>    бей, бек, заде, зуль, кызы, оглы, оль, паша, уль, хан, шах, эд, эль,
>    эр, напр.: **Абд аль-Кадир, Турсун-заде, Мамед-оглы, Явер-кызы,
>    Измаил-бей, Кемаль-паша, Мирза-хан, Ахмед-шах** (но: Чингисхан).
>    Примечание 1. Часть ибн пишется в таких именах раздельно, напр.: Ибн
>    Сина, Ахмед ибн Абдуллах. Примечание 2. Начальная часть Бен- может
>    писаться в таких именах как через дефис, так и раздельно, напр.:
>    Бен-Гурион, но Бен Барка. Примечание 3 (к пп. 2 и 3). Написание
>    конкретных личных имен этих групп уточняется по энциклопедическому
>    словарю.

http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=337

Нужно учитывать и то, что 21 июня 1934 г. правитель Турции Мустафа Кемаль принял "Закон о фамилиях". Согласно закону, все граждане Турецкой республики должны были получить фамилию.  Каждого турка обязали взять фамилию до 2 июля 1936 г. Если этого не происходило, то фамилии давал вали (наместник провинции), каймакан (начальник округа) или другое, уполномоченное ими лицо.

В дополнение к этому 26 ноября того же года был принят закон об "Отмене приставок к именам в виде прозвищ и званий" (т.е. эфенди, бей, паша). Согласно этим законам сам Мустафа Кемаль получил фамилию Ататюрк (Atatürk) — "отец турок".

Так что, если это фамилия после 1936 года, то отдельные из этих  слов могут войти в саму фамилию и писаться без дефиса.